# Issues placing buttons on page

Tags: css, button

I have a few questions with the code below.

1) I went to the Twitter site to get the code to embed a "Tweet" button but am having two issues - a) the button just shows up as a link and b) the text that I had pre-loaded into the tweet box does not appear

2) I'd like the two yellow buttons to be centered on the page, next to each other. Can someone help with the positioning?

3) Can I get rid of the hyperlink on the text within the button? Right now, the link only works if you click on the text (I'd like it to work if you click anywhere on the button).

Really appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
<!-- doc type declaration lets browser know which xhtml doc type declaration we are using -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<title>SAMPLE TEXT</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">


#wtf_title {font-family: "Garamond"; font-weight: bold; font-size: 200%; padding-top:50px}

#intro_text {font-family: "Helvetica", serif; color: black; padding-top:10px; 
font-style: italic;}

#reason {font-family: "Helvetica", serif; color: white; padding-top:50px; padding-bottom:50px;}

#credit 
{
    font-family: "helvetica"; 
    font-size: 20%; 
    color: black; 
    }

#button1 {padding-left:20px;}

button{
color:#08233e;
font:2.4em Futura, ‘Century Gothic’, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
font-size:70%;
padding:14px;
background:url(overlay.png) repeat-x center #ffcc00;background-color:rgba(255,204,0,1);
border:1px solid #ffcc00;
-moz-border-radius:10px;-webkit-border-radius:10px;border-radius:10px;
border-bottom:1px solid #9f9f9f;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0      rgba(255,255,255,0.5);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
cursor:pointer;
}

button:hover{background-color:rgba(255,204,0,0.8);}

button:active{position:absolute;top:100px; left:50px}

</style>


<body>

<div id="wtf_title" >
<center>sample text<br/>
</div>

<hr noshade size=8 width="53%">

<div id="intro_text" >
<center>Sample text
</div>

<button>
<center><a href="" class="button1">sample text</a>
</button>

<button>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.americanbar.org" class="button2">sample text</a>    
</button>

<div id="twitter-share-button"; style="position: absolute; top: 2px;" >
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data- url="http://www.whatthefuckhaslebronjamesdone.com" data-text="Check this out:" data- count="none" data-hashtags="WTFLBJ">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s) [0];if(!d.getElementById(id)) {js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.in sertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>

<div id="fb_share"; style="position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 90px;" >
<a name="fb_share"></a> 
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" 
    type="text/javascript">
</script>
</div>


<div id="credit"; style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 32%;" >
This site was created by <a href="http://www.twitter.com/varunsshetty">Varun Shetty</a> and    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/bcfromblo">Bobby Corp</a>. Inspired by LBJ and <a href="http://www.whatthefuckhasobamadonesofar.com">WTF Obama</a>. Bobby loves Lebron; Varun loves the idea of Lebron.
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is causing your specific problem, but you're not allowed to have anything above the <!DOCTYPE> element. This will cause the browser to render the page in quirks mode, and then all sorts of craziness can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid in many places, you really need to put your HTML through a WC3 validator before posting here, it would save you a lot of time and effort.

Here is a jsfiddle to start you out:
http://jsfiddle.net/RPc95/

For making the entire button click-able you either need to create a proper submit / button element or style a href to look like a button.

Comment: your solution worked for putting the buttons in the middle of the page, but it had the weird of side effect of including three random characters on the page as well that i cant seem to get rid of: a lower case a with a caret over it, a euro symbol, and a bracket.